# Wake on lan via phy activity

Tags: networking, ethernet, wakeup, wakeonlan

I am trying to enable wake on lan via phy activity which I would assume any network access to this network card should wake it.

I can wake on lan via magic packet and that works

```
sudo ethtool enp4s0
```

Settings for `enp4s0`:

```
        Supported ports: [  ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 2500Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: p
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

I have modified `/etc/network/interfaces` to add the "p" option so it should wake on phy activity instead of magic packet

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp4s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.12/24
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        bridge-ports enp4s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        up ethtool -s enp4s0 wol p
```

I can try to ping 192.168.1.12 from a windows machine and this machine does not wake. If I switch it back to wake on magic packet it boots every time

Comment: Wake on magic is how it is supposed to work. https://www.energystar.gov/products/low_carbon_it_campaign/implementation_resources_enterprises/wake_on_lan#:~:text=Wake%2Don%2DLAN%20(WOL,reserved%20for%20the%20network%20card.